# Custom Post Login Action Hook in Liferay 7 using Blade

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I am developing a liferay project where there are 2 sites, 1 for Admin and 1 for users. Admin and users are differentiated based on user groups. when an admin logs in he should be redirected to Admin page and when user logs in, they should be redirected to User page. How can we achieve this functionality in Liferay 7 using Blade or Hook plugin? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a plugin example here:

https://www.e-systems.tech/blog/-/blogs/liferay-7-how-to-get-a-session-object-after-login-

Basically, if you want a post login hook, this example should be enough.

To use liferay services, in the new style, you will need some references

```
private Portal portal;
private UserLocalService userLocalService;

@Reference
private void setUserLocalService(UserLocalService service){
    this.userLocalService=service;
}

@Reference
private void setPortalUtil(Portal portal){
    this.portal=portal;
}
```

now, to get user information and more data about the portal

```
final long companyId = portal.getCompanyId(request);
final HttpSession session = request.getSession();
```

This line should be useful to:

```
User user = (User)session.getAttribute(WebKeys.USER);
```

For redirection: use the redirect parameter in the URL.

or, this code would help..

```
Map params = new HashMap();

params.put("p_l_id", new String[] {"PRI.1.1"});

LastPath lastPath = new LastPath("/c", "/portal/layout", params);

ses.setAttribute(WebKeys.LAST_PATH, lastPath);
```

For this to work, you might also check the auth.forward.by.last.path property

Comment: But how do we get the User info and user group and how do we redirect the user or admin to their respective page. Sorry I am new to liferay-7 so need some help with the code??

Comment: let me know if you could solve your issue, I am curious about it.

Comment: it worked to get to a different page. but how do we redirect to a different url, something like www.sample.com.

Comment: Hum. That is quite different.. I am thinking that you could make them land in a JSP that make the restrictions with extra freedom. But be careful cause Liferay security filter might interfere here, depending on your configuration.

Comment: I will surely give it a try. Thanks @victor the functionality what I was expecting worked absolutely fine.